# PrimeFaces page "hangs" on update of element containing JS "document.write"

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Why PrimeFaces command button can't update element containing JavaScript `<script>document.write("some text")</script>` element? Browser "hangs" on update of such element.

for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>
        <title>my page</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:commandButton
                id="pushMeButton"
                value="push me"
                update="testPanel"
                action="#{myManagedBean.doNothing()}">
            </p:commandButton>
        </h:form>

        <p:panel id="testPanel">
            <script>
                document.write("test text 1");
            </script>
            <script>
                document.write("test text 2");
            </script>

           <h:outputText value="#{myManagedBean.getSomeText()}" />
        </p:panel>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

after pressing "pushMeButton", browser shows only empty page with text "test text 1" and "hangs" (icon in firefox tab shows that page is still loading indefinitely, but there are no active request in firebug).

Partial response received by browser after button was pressed looks correct:

```
<partial-response id="j_id1">
    <changes>
        <update id="testPanel">
            <![CDATA[
            <div id="testPanel" class="ui-panel ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" data-widget="widget_testPanel">
                <div id="testPanel_content" class="ui-panel-content ui-widget-content">
                    <script>
                        document.write("test text 1");
                    </script>
                    <script>
                        document.write("test text 2");
                    </script>
                    some text from managed bean method getSomeText()
                </div>
            </div>
            <script id="testPanel_s" type="text/javascript">
                PrimeFaces.cw("Panel","widget_testPanel",{id:"testPanel",widgetVar:"widget_testPanel"});
            </script>
            ]]>
        </update>
        <update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"><![CDATA[1747871418605077113:5684199653317714547]]></update>
    </changes>
</partial-response>
```

I am using PrimeFaces: 5.2.5 and Mojarra: 2.2.8

I can reproduce behavior on: Firefox v44.0.2 and IE v11, but on Chrome v48 everything works as expected (same page is shown without changes).

xhtml sniped presented above is just simplified version of problem I am solving. I use "document.write" because my web application "imports" some HTML parts from legacy system which can not be changed (I import menu from Liferay portal).
If I change "document.write" to something else, for example `document.getElementById('someExistingElementId').innerHTML = 'New text';` everything works fine.

It looks like comment of BalusC *"I think I see the root cause. IE6/7/8 unfortunately doesn't run the embedded scripts when document.write() is been used to replace the DOM"* (http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=18937&start=20) is related to my problem, but I don't understand why it does not work and if it is possible to make it work on modern browsers.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. In your example there is nothing to update in the script. Also the commandButton doesn't call any action in the bean. It might be a bit more useful if you'd make the code a bit closer to what you actually have.

Comment: I updated my example: I added action which calls empty managed bean method and I added h:outputText  to my panel and updated post response accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not related to PrimeFaces or JSF directly - it is javascript working principle.

> "If it is used after an HTML document is fully loaded, it will delete
>   all existing HTML." (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp)

I can reproduce similar situation using HTML and JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>    
        <p>Click the button to trigger a function</p>    
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                document.write("test text 1");
            }
        </script>    
   </body>
</html>
```

Partial update updates document which is already loaded - this is reason why only "test text 1" is presented after button is clicked. Because all document is overwritten after first `<script>document.write("test text 1");<script>` is executed.

Firefox "hangs" because "document.close" was not called (if document output stream is not open "document.write" will open it, so it is necessary to close it).

So resume is: it is not possible use `document.write(...);` in JSF pages if that part of page can be updated with ajax call.

In most cases `document.write(...)` should be avoided in JSF pages, because it is not always possible to control which part of page will be updated. For example OmniFace FullAjaxExceptionHandler will execute update="@all" after exception, so error page can't have any `document.write(...)` statements.